# How to set `EnableExternalImages = true` for LocalReport

Tags: asp.net-core, rdlc, reporting-services-2016

I am using reporting package - AspNetCore.Reporting -2.1.0. I want to print my RDLC report having an external image. During rendering to pdf an error occurred.

```
An error occurred during local report processing.;Report 'Payslip' contains external images. The EnableExternalImages property has not been set for this report.
```

Rendering part of my code:

```
string reportFileName = "Payslip.rdlc";
if (paySlip.IsHourlySalary)
    reportFileName = "Payslip.rdlc";
else
{
    reportFileName = "PaySlipForAnnual.rdlc";
}
string ReportPath;
if (_webHostEnvironment != null)
    ReportPath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "\\TMReports", reportFileName);
else
{
    ReportPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "/TMReports", reportFileName);
}
LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport(ReportPath);

message += " Before localReport.SetParameters(param);";
message += " Before localReport.DataSources.Add(cd);";
localReport.AddDataSource("dsPaySlip", dtPaySlip); // Add  datasource here    

message += " Before  byte[] bytes = localReport.Render(";
var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, 1, reportParams, mimeType);
               
return result.MainStream;
```

Answer (score 6):

Run this before Rendering

```
localReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
```

Edit:

Seems the open source library you are using does not expose the variable nor the method you need.

[image]

But the methods are there in a private variable of the sealed class.

[image: AspNetCore.Reporting Lib]

So you can still change it's value by reflection...

It's not pretty but it will get the job done.

```
AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalReport rpt = new AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalReport(yourReportPath);
BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;
FieldInfo field = rpt.GetType().GetField("localReport", bindFlags);
object rptObj = field.GetValue(rpt);
Type type = rptObj.GetType();
PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty("EnableExternalImages");
pi.SetValue(rptObj, true, null);
```

Comment: It is not possible to set in asp.net core 5. It is possible for older asp.net reporting services.

Comment: My bad. But the method seems to be still publicly accessible, you may need to create your own LocalReport class by extending AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalReport. If you need example code, please give me time.

Comment: @NandanKumarDas Does the updated answer works for you?

Comment: i used in .net5 class library, and worked.

Comment: for me also worked with dotnet 6. thanks