# How to enable external images at rdlc dotnet core

Tags: image, .net-core, parameter-passing, rdlc

I want to pass an image as parameter to my RDLC in dotnet core using enableexternalimage properity.

Comment: I had answer a similar question before, see if this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67189335/6670491

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and these the steps

```
 //define the paramters Dictionary
       Dictionary<string, string> Param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       //get the image 
       string ImagePath = $"{ this._environment.WebRootPath }\\car.png";
       Bitmap bitMapIm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ImagePath);
       Graphics graphicIm = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapIm);
       
        //the value that will be sended to the rdlc
        string ImageAsParamter = "";
        
        //transform the image ToBase64String
        using (var image = new Bitmap(ImagePath))
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                ImageAsParamter = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }

        //assign the parameter value
        Param.Add("ImageDamages", ImageAsParamter);

//and finally add image to your rdlc with the following properties.
```

[Image Parameter Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgBPd.png)